# Перенос текста в шапке html

Tags: html, css

Как мне перенести номер телефона под "Contact now!" ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы было вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    margin: 33px auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header .menu_top li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

header .menu_top li a{
    display: block;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu_top">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="img/phone.png" alt="">
            <p>Contact now!</p>
            <p>(012) 345-6789</p>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
    </header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Было бы удобнее, если бы Вы добавили в вопрос не скриншоты, а непосредственно сами коды (ещё лучше — в форме html/css/js (Ctrl+M) ). [edit]

Comment: я добавил код html и css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае достаточно поставить тег-разделитель [`<br/>`](http://htmlbook.ru/index.php/html/br), а после него вписать номер телефона (напоминаю, что всё это должно быть внутри `<p></p>`. Центрирование и стили оставляю Вам :)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header{
    margin: 33px auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

header .menu_top li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

header .menu_top li a{
    display: block;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu_top">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="img/phone.png" alt="">
            <p>Contact now! <br/> (012) 345-6789</p>
            <p>(012) 345-6789</p>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
    </header>  
</body>
</html>
```